# Type hinting for object with autospec'd dependencies

Tags: python, pycharm, mocking, type-hinting, linter

I am creating tests for some controller objects that obviously have dependencies. I want to test that it's interacting correctly with the dependencies without instantiating them for obvious reasons (database connections). So I have a class like

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, some_dependency: InterfaceB):
    self.some_dependency: InterfaceB = some_dependency

  def do_thing(self, x):
    self.some_dependecy.do_subtask(necessary_data=x)
```

And I want to test that it's correctly passing the value down to its dependency so I do something like this

```
def test_do_thing():
  a: A = A(some_dependency=create_autospec(InterfaceB))
  a.do_thing(1)
  assert a.some_dependency.do_subtask.called_with(necessary_data=1)
```

but the code completion/linter is going to complain that do_subtask is a function and doesn't have a called_with property, so I have to do

```
do_subtask: Mock = cast(Mock, a.some_dependency.do_subtask)
assert do_subtask.called_with(necessary_data=1)
```

which, if you imagine a controller with multiple dependencies, or even just using multiple methods of one dependency, it gets pretty tedious and not very DRY and is infact very WET (What? Eeek Terrible). Is there any solution that does any one of the follwing in order of preference

1. Magically hints that A is of type A, but all of its dependencies are autospeced, so they're of the type that they are, but then their methods would be mocks?
2. A type hint that says a variable is an autospec of a type, so it has all the methods of the type, but they're actually Mock objects?
3. Just a less repetitive way to declare to the pycharm linter that they're mocks

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if my answer could be useful for you, and if not excuse me; surely not all your questions will have an answer from the code below. I don't have checked anything about *PyCharm hints*.

I have executed the code below in my `IDE PyCharm` and the test is passed successfully.
I have changed your `assert` because I use `unittest.mock`.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import create_autospec

class InterfaceB:
    def do_subtask(self, necessary_data):
        pass

class A:
  def __init__(self, some_dependency: InterfaceB):
    self.some_dependency: InterfaceB = some_dependency

  def do_thing(self, x):
    self.some_dependency.do_subtask(necessary_data=x)


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_do_thing(self):
        a: A = A(some_dependency=create_autospec(InterfaceB))
        a.do_thing(1)
        # ---> Note that I have changed your assert!
        #assert a.some_dependency.do_subtask.called_with(necessary_data=1)
        a.some_dependency.do_subtask.assert_called_once_with(necessary_data=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As you can see I have defined a class `InterfaceB` with a method `do_subtask()`.

The method `test_do_thing()` verifies only that: *the execution of method `do_thing(1)` calls one time the method `do_subtask(1)`*.

Comment: this is a perfect implementation of my code example, however, my concern wasn't the code, but type hinting. In this example (as in my example) if I type a.some_dependency.do_subtask and press '.' then the autocomplete is not going to give me options such as assert_called_once_with, it'll just give me whatever methods you can call on a function. If you wanted the linter to be aware that it's a mock you would have to make a ```do_subtask: Mock = typing.cast(Mock, self.some_dependency.do_subtask)``` but I don't wanna do that everytime, I want to hint that it's all mocks in one line

Comment: @Lachlan I'm sorry but I'm not able to help you about your exactly question. If you find a satisfactory answer, please write it in this post.